# Storing actively updated fields in the database

Tags: database-design, postgresql

I have a database with one of the table storing articles. For every article I need to store the number of times it was viewed. Now, my idea is to store this value in the database and update it every time someone visits the page with that article and I am considering two alternatives now:

1. Create a column `views` in the table `articles` and update it.
2. Create a separate table `view_count` with FK pointer to the article and the number views for that article.

My question is: is there any difference between these two approaches in terms of speed and why? Are there any better alternatives?

The database I use is PostgreSQL.

**Note**, that I am not considering the different ways of accumulating those values in separate files, outside of database and later inserting because i) we do not get as many hits ii) the feature in minor and if it would require such a hassle we would rather abandon it and use some other service for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The differences of two proposals are quite subtle, here's how I see them:

**Same table**

- keeping it in the same table will allow you to retrieve it at lower cost
- updates might be locking the parts of DB that other queries in the queue need slowing them down
- making tables wider increases I/O (it always increase I/O for table scans, but for index lookups it is not so straight forward - when record size becomes bigger then the filesystem's block size then even the index lookups will have to do 2x more I/O; or `n`x more I/O depending on the record size/block size, if the record size is much less then the block size then the effect for the index lookups depends on the type of query/order of the data on the disk - if choosing records from the same block you will feel the performance hit, if choosing sparse data you will not feel it)

**Separate tables**

- updates will happen on a smaller table so less I/O (locks might still be necessary to check foreign key, depending on isolation level, but should be shorter as there is less I/O)
- retrieving data for an article requires a join which will increase I/O
- if the view count is a new feature not present on most of your other records you are also saving space and even though join might increase required I/O, this might give better performance

**Notes**:
The comment apply, but are subtle: record size will probably not get significantly affected to influence all queries. The benefits of less I/O with separate table might not be perceivable.

Comment: @maksymko, thanks - I updated the answer a bit, the old text was not precise enough regarding the index lookups.

Answer (score 0):

If the `articles` table gets a lot of writes than updating the column might be a bit slower because of the table locks while writing.

Using a separate table is only a little bit slower/heavier to read but is lightest in terms of updates. But after loads of writes you can easily rebuild the table without much performance penalty since it will be quite a light table.

If your database doesn't have a high load than I would take the easy option of adding a column though.

Answer (score 0):

I have one more approach, where I do the update later in the day or when the traffic to the site is too less.
I would do the job in this way, when ever any user reads the articles, there user id will be stored in a new table, and later through script I can update How many times the article have been read by the users.

Comment: This still falls under the separate table option. Since the cardinality of the relationship is 1:0,1 I can't see benefit of having the view column at two places with one updated periodically.